# Is it possible to configure influx CLI to format timestamp data returned as human readable - but to the nearest second?

Tags: influxql

I have been using the [`precision`](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2/tools/influxql-shell/#precision) influx cli command to format the time value in data returned from InfluxQL select queries.

The documentation says you can have ONE of `rfc3339 | h | m | s | ms | u | ns`.

When I choose `rfc3339` I get the time stamp fomatted thus:

```
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┓
┃ index ┃              time              ┃ data ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━┫
┃      1┃2023-09-25T18:33:50.094052584Z  ┃ 7.00 ┃
...
```

Is it possible to format the time to be rounded and diplayed to the nearest second? What I want is this:

```
┏━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━┳━━━━━━┓
┃ index ┃         time         ┃ data ┃
┣━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━╋━━━━━━┫
┃      1┃2023-09-25T18:33:50Z  ┃ 7.00 ┃
...
```

And for *Bonus Marks* can I make it display in my local time zone not utc?